# Filter an array of objects searching all key-value pairs

Tags: javascript

Let's say I have an array of objects in JavaScript that looks something like this:

```
namesArray = [
  { name: 'John', friend: 'Steve', brother: 'Jeff', sister: 'Karen'},
  { name: 'Sarah', friend: 'Joan', brother: 'Marvin', sister: 'Diana'},
  { name: 'Morris', friend: 'Tanya', brother: 'Mike', sister: 'Lisa'},
  { name: 'Brian', friend: 'Tim', brother: 'Andrew', sister: 'Tanya'},
];
```

If I wanted to filter out the objects in the above array that contain the value "Tanya" into a new array, how would I go about it? The new array would look like this:

```
newArray = [
  { name: 'Morris', friend: 'Tanya', brother: 'Mike', sister: 'Lisa'},
  { name: 'Brian', friend: 'Tim', brother: 'Andrew', sister: 'Tanya'},
];
```

Comment: Have you had a look at [Array.prototype.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)?

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for `filter`

```js
namesArray = [
  { name: 'John', friend: 'Steve', brother: 'Jeff', sister: 'Karen'},
  { name: 'Sarah', friend: 'Joan', brother: 'Marvin', sister: 'Diana'},
  { name: 'Morris', friend: 'Tanya', brother: 'Mike', sister: 'Lisa'},
  { name: 'Brian', friend: 'Tim', brother: 'Andrew', sister: 'Tanya'},
];

const output = namesArray.filter(obj => 
  Object.values(obj).findIndex(val => val === 'Tanya') > -1
)

console.log(output)
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a short solution that requires `Object.values` ([caniuse?](https://caniuse.com/#search=object.values)):

```js
var namesArray = [
  { name: 'John', friend: 'Steve', brother: 'Jeff', sister: 'Karen' },
  { name: 'Sarah', friend: 'Joan', brother: 'Marvin', sister: 'Diana' },
  { name: 'Morris', friend: 'Tanya', brother: 'Mike', sister: 'Lisa' },
  { name: 'Brian', friend: 'Tim', brother: 'Andrew', sister: 'Tanya' },
];

var tanyaOnly = namesArray.filter(e => Object.values(e).indexOf("Tanya") > -1);

console.log(tanyaOnly);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use of `includes` would be much easier.

```js
const namesArray = [
  { name: 'John', friend: 'Steve', brother: 'Jeff', sister: 'Karen'},
  { name: 'Sarah', friend: 'Joan', brother: 'Marvin', sister: 'Diana'},
  { name: 'Morris', friend: 'Tanya', brother: 'Mike', sister: 'Lisa'},
  { name: 'Brian', friend: 'Tim', brother: 'Andrew', sister: 'Tanya'},
];
let filteredArray = namesArray.filter(x => Object.values(x).includes('Tanya') === false);
console.log(filteredArray);
```